# Laravel convert query mysql to model query

Tags: php, laravel

I have model uptime. How I can do this query with model query?

```
SELECT server_id, COUNT(*) status FROM uptime WHERE online = 0 GROUP BY server_id
```

I try:

```
Uptime::where('online', 0)->get();
```

But this is not correctly. I need with `COUNT(*)` and group by select.

Comment: Read the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent

Comment: Also https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Uptime::whereOnline(0)
    ->groupBy('server_id')
    ->select('server_id', DB::raw('count(*) as status'))
    ->get();
```

`whereOnline` is shortcut from `where('online', 0)`

Answer (score 0):

```
Uptime::select('server_id', DB::raw('COUNT(*) as status'))
        ->where('online',0)
        ->groupBy('server_id')
        ->get();
```

Answer (score -1):

according to laravel docs [Raw Expressions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#raw-expressions)

this code is appropriate way to `COUNT(*)` and `GROUP BY` on your queries

```
DB::table('uptime')->select(DB::raw('COUNT(*) as status'))
    ->where('online',0)
    ->groupBy('server_id')
    ->get();
```

**Raw statements will be injected into the query as strings, so you should be extremely careful to not create SQL injection vulnerabilities.**